# How to make logged in user Like only once on a post?

Tags: php, sql

I have a Like buton on every post in my blog, and I want to make logged in user to Like a post only once...

I have this three tables in my database:

table `tbladminXshouts`

```
CREATE TABLE `tbladminXshouts` (
  `admin_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

table `tbladmin`

```
CREATE TABLE `tbladmin` (
  `admin_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `admin_usr_name` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `admin_pwd` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;
```

table `shouts`

```
CREATE TABLE `shouts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `lund` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `LundaBlogg` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post` text NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `userName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `lund` (`lund`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=25 ;
```

Now Im using this code, and the users can Like the posts how many times they want.
What sql should I write to make my users Like only once on a post?

```
<?php
class Like
{
    function like()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Gilla'])) 
        {   
            $sql="UPDATE shouts SET likes =  likes +1 WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."'"; 
            $result=mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but please sanitize the input before placing it in a sql statement to prevent sql injections

Comment: **Careful!** The `mysql_*` functions are [old and should not be used anymore](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). Please have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli), which are better [MySQL API choices](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: Write a query that selects the items they have marked as like.  Do not display anything that allows them to like these items again.

Comment: @Mark Thanks, Im gonna take a look at that...

Comment: @Helge Helwig Thanks, Im gonna take a look at that...

Comment: @Dan Bracuk Thanks, but what do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to create another table, linking "shouts" with your users table, to keep record of every Like. 
The total amount of Likes for a post can be computed out of that table (i.e. 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_shouts WHERE id = bla'), and you'd have to make sure that a user can only 'post' one time in that table for one post.

Your current infrastructure does not look like it could handle your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you mean these tabel: CREATE TABLE `tbladminXshouts` (
  `admin_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1; , or maybe Im wrong...

Comment: @BrunoChavez - The purpose of `tbladminXshouts` seems to be to link `tbladmin` to `shouts`.  Niek is correct, you're going to need a new table.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thanks. Ok, I understand... Can you give me a help on how to crreate one more table that I need?